# How work for RewriteRule in .htaccess (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have made a virtual host as **school-laravel.dev**

My project **.htaccess** file is as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

```
<FilesMatch "^\.env">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
```

I want if user **enters school-laravel.dev/whatever** it should be redirect to **school-laravel.dev/students**
How to rewrite this rule above in .htaccess

**i tried as but its not working**

```
RewriteRule ^test\/?(.*)$ "http://demo.school-pre.com/students/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in htaccess for redirect.

This will **#Redirect from old domain to new domain with full path and query string:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://demo.school-pre.com/students%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Also I found "[ScottPhillips](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)" git-hub page where he is explained awesome how to use htaccess on various conditions.

Below is his examples.

```
#301 Redirects for .htaccess

#Redirect a single page:
Redirect 301 /pagename.php http://www.domain.com/pagename.html

#Redirect an entire site:
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/

#Redirect an entire site to a sub folder
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/subfolder/

#Redirect a sub folder to another site
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://www.domain.com/

#This will redirect any file with the .html extension to use the same filename but use the .php extension instead.
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com$1.php

##
#You can also perform 301 redirects using rewriting via .htaccess.
##

#Redirect from old domain to new domain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect to www location
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

#Redirect to www location with subdirectory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/directory/index.html [R=301,NC]

#Redirect from old domain to new domain with full path and query string:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]

#Redirect from old domain with subdirectory to new domain w/o subdirectory including full path and query string:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirname/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.katcode.com/%1 [R=302,NC]

Rewrite and redirect URLs with query parameters (files placed in root directory)

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1
Desired destination URL:

http://www.example.com/path-to-new-location/
.htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
Redirect URLs with query parameters (files placed in subdirectory)

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/sub-dir/index.php?id=1
Desired destination URL:

http://www.example.com/path-to-new-location/
.htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
Redirect one clean URL to a new clean URL

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/old-page/
Desired destination URL:
http://www.example.com/new-page/
.htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-page/?$ $1/new-page$2 [R=301,L]
Rewrite and redirect URLs with query parameter to directory based structure, retaining query string in URL root level

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=100
Desired destination URL:

http://www.example.com/100/
.htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
Rewrite URLs with query parameter to directory based structure, retaining query string parameter in URL subdirectory

Original URL:
http://www.example.com/index.php?category=fish
Desired destination URL:
http://www.example.com/category/fish/
.htaccess syntax:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?category/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
Domain change – redirect all incoming request from old to new domain (retain path)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
If you do not want to pass the path in the request to the new domain, change the last row to:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/ [R=301,L]

#From blog.oldsite.com -> www.somewhere.com/blog/
retains path and query, and eliminates xtra blog path if domain is blog.oldsite.com/blog/
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/ blog
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.somewhere.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.somewhere.com/blog/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Place Laravel in your document root folder.

Step 2. Place the following `.htaccess file` in your **document root folder**.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```